# How to change retina display system preferences in OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa, retina-display

I am wondering if there is a way to programmatically change the current display mode that is set in System Preferences?  Specifically, I want to be able to detect and switch between the 5 Retina display modes on the new Retina MacBook Pro.

I looked through the `NSUserDefaults NSGlobalDomain` to try to find how to change the current display mode in System Preferences, and couldn't find anything relating to the display at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out http://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/vi9yf/set_your_retina_macbook_pros_resolution_to/ -- uses the private API CGSGetDisplayModeDescriptionOfLength and CGSConfigureDisplayMode to set. Code's included in the kindly distributed .app bundle.

I just wrote up a lengthy post about my endeavours in trying to answer the same question - see 
 http://garethjenkins.com/2012/07/01/investigating-a-high-resolution-retina-utility-for-macbook-pro-1x-and-2x-modes/

Comment: I don't suppose you know the actual source code RDM.app is using to discover/apply retina display modes? It seems to have been pulled from the github pages linked in the reddit post. I'm working on a much nicer/more usable version of essentially the same app, and have it working with public api's (non-retina of course), but I'm not really familiar enough with Core Foundation to go hacking private API's myself.